# How to do async OkHttp request in another class and then callback to activity

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I want to move my OkHttp async request to a separate class as I use it multiple times in multiple activities in my application. Is this possible? I've read a lot about it but can't find a solution for me.

MainActivity.java

```
public void mainActivityMethod(String JSONData) {
     // Handle JSONData string
}
```

MyClass.java

```
public void doRequest() {

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                // Fetch request data
                String JSONData = response.body().string();

                mainActivityMethod(JSONData);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [OTTO](https://square.github.io/otto/). You can use [OTTO](https://square.github.io/otto/) to publish an event and then subscribe to that event in the activity. It helps you in loose coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Rather this one. First create the Interface for it and implement it in needed activities. After that, create an `AsyncTask` to do network related stuff. In the `AsyncTask`'s `onPost` method, call the `Activity`'s implement method to reflect needed changes in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

when you need to use a function of another class just create an instance of that class and call the function, like :

```
MyWantedClass myWantedClass= new MyWantedClass;
myWantedClass.functionNeeded();
```

Comment: That works if I want to call the function and lets say just put a simple `System.out.println("Hello");` But if I call `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("Test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` inside `mainActivityMethod` I get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is AsyncTask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Remember to subclass it. You can do it in your MainActivity if static. Here is a simple example from the documentation

```
 private static class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     //executed in background
     int result
     //call...
     //set 0 or 1 depending or the error code
     return result;
 } 

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //in case you want to post any progress
     // on UI thread
 } 

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //when the call is finished
     // on UI thread

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this solved by now.  The easy answer is to create an interface that main activity supports and pass the mainActivity via the interface to MyClass so MyClass makes the call to the interface.  I would tell you more but I suspect no one will ever read this.